# python json.dumps() and insert data into mysql 1064 error

Tags: python-3.x

When I use Pyhton's pymysql and json modules to convert list data to json data, and then insert these converted json data into mysql table, occurs 1064 error.
Using `json.dumps()` to convert python list data into json data,then insert these converted json data into mysql, occurs **1064 error**.

But when I use `json.dumps(json.dumps())`, insert successfull. Why? 
My English is poor, this is my problem description.

```py
import pymysql
import json

# sql 
SelectTemplate_1 = '''SELECT id FROM {tb} ORDER BY id ASC;'''
Insert_school_branch = '''INSERT INTO school_resource_auth (school_id, 
                          {field}) VALUES({v1}, {v2}) ON DUPLICATE KEY
                          UPDATE {field}={v2};'''

with DB.cursor() as cursor:
        sel_school_sql = SelectTemplate_1.format(tb="schools")
        cursor.execute(sel_school_sql)
        school_id = cursor.fetchall()
        if school_id is None:
            raise ValueError("nothing!")
        else:
            pass

        sel_skillup_sql = SelectTemplate_1.format(tb="skillup_resources")
        cursor.execute(sel_skillup_sql)
        skillup_id = cursor.fetchall()
        if skillup_id is None:
            raise ValueError("nothing")
        else:
            pass
        new_skill = []
        for i in skillup_id:
            new_skill.append(i[0])

        for sid in school_id:
            insert_dic1 = {
                "field": "skillup_resource_ids",
                "v1": sid[0],
                "v2": json.dumps(json.dumps(new_skill, separators=(',', ':')))
            }
        insert_skillup_sql = Insert_school_branch.format(**insert_dic1)
        cursor.execute(insert_skillup_sql)
        print("OK")

# "v2": json.dumps(new_skill, searators=(',',':'))
# insert thses data into mysql occurs 1064 error
# when use double json.dumps() that is OK, like above.
```

Answer (score 0):

1064 error refers to mysql syntax error. Make sure that your mysql query snytax is correct.